# Unable to display both alert buttons on page loading in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a code that displays both the alert buttons on loading a page.However,I could load only one of the alert buttons(init2) i.e init1 pop up is not appearing. Below attached is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
 // fname will be executed when the <body> tag loads
 function addOnLoad(fname){ 
    // Define this function

    window.onload=fname;
}

// init1 and init2 should be alerted when the body tag loads
addOnLoad(function (){alert('init1!'); });
addOnLoad(function (){ alert('init2!'); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Output I'm getting :

[image]

I donot understand the reason why  the alert button for init1 is not printing.I want both of them to get printed.Any suggestions would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Your `addOnLoad` function is replacing the event handler by setting `window.onLoad`, rather than adding a new handler. If you want to add an additional handler you need to use

```
window.addEventListener('load', fname);
```

Also, note that the browser will only ever show one alert at a time, so the alerts will appear in order rather than at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a function to `window.onload`, then overwriting it by assigning another function to that same `window.onload`. Because the previous function was overwritten, only the last added function will execute.

Depending on what your issue actually is, you will either need to wrap all your code in `window.onload`: (this is how jQuery does it)

```
window.onload = function(){
  alert('init1');
  alert('init2');
  someOtherCode();
}
```

Or you will need to define a custom function that will accept multiple functions to execute on window load. However, I do not recommend this second solution: what if you try to add a function after the window has already loaded? You will need to account for this possibility, as well as other edge cases. For ease of use, just wrap your whole code in `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1):

the *onload* property can only contain one function.  Your 2nd addOnLoad is overwriting the first.  Try:

```
    addOnLoad(function (){alert('init1!'); alert('init2!');});
```